# javascript - for loop to make events

Tags: javascript, events, function, for-loop

I'm using a script where I need to make multiple events to make a popup appear.

I tried this, but it doesnt work:

```
for (i=0;i<=storingen;i++)
    {
        $("#storing" + i).click(function(){ centerPopup(); loadPopup(); });
    }
```

The output should be:

```
$("#storing0").click(function(){ centerPopup(); loadPopup(); });
$("#storing1").click(function(){ centerPopup(); loadPopup(); });
$("#storing2").click(function(){ centerPopup(); loadPopup(); });
$("#storing3").click(function(){ centerPopup(); loadPopup(); });
```

etc.

But the amount of divs with the id **#storing(number here)** is variable, so i wanted to make this, but it doesnt work...

I get the storingen variable from php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">aantalstoringen('.$aantalstoringen.')</script>
```

which i pick up in the js file like this:

```
function aantalstoringen(storingen){
    storingen=storingen;
}
```

I did an **alert(storingen)**, which traced the right number, so that is ok.

COuld it be that the for loop doesnt work because that isnt in the **aantalstoringen function**, but in another function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

I used this tutorial to make the javascript:
http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/#popup1
and the script you get is this:
http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/popupjquery/popup.js

Comment: I suggest you give all these elements the same class and just do `$('.classname').click(function(){...});`.

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that this function is made [like you can see in the linked popup.js file] to show specific divs.
Each div has a different ID because the content is different, so i cant use that function that searches for every element with ID storing*

I'm sorry if I'm not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't create dozens of event listeners that call the same handler. You create one listener on a higher level in the DOM and make it react only if the ID of the target matches the pattern.

This is why libs like jQuery are teaching kids bad manners... -.-

Comment: Yeah, you know, I realised that the script I used is totally not handy to use here, as they all call the same handler...
I have to make different eventlisteners which call different handlers to make this work...
how stupid of me..

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`[name^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector instead:

```
$('[id^="storing"]').click(function(){ ... });
```

Basically, it's saying "find all elements whose ID begins with 'storing'."

If you need it more explicit, you can test the `id` inside a [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to apply better filtering. e.g.

```
$('[id^="storing"]')
  // make sure all IDs end in a number
  .each(function(i,e){
    if (/\d$/.test(e.id)) {
      // now that we only have ids that begin with storing and end in
      // a number, bind the click event
      $(e).click(function(e){ ... });
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve with the mapping... you will end up with an array of strings and you cannot bind event handlers to them.

Comment: @FelixKling: True, still waking up. Should probably put the logic in the click statement or an each statement

Comment: In that case I would use `.filter` instead ;) No worries, good morning :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be any number of things.  It would help if you showed us more of the code, like all of the `aantalstoringen` function.

The following should work:

```
function aantalstoringen(storingen) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        for (i=0;i<=storingen;i++) {
            $("#storing" + i).click(function(){ centerPopup(); loadPopup(); });
        }
    });
}
```

That said, this is a really bad way to do this.  I would have each of your elements also include `class="storing"`.  Then you don't have to get the number of objects from the server:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".storing").click(function(){ centerPopup(); loadPopup(); });
});
```

Comment: I showed you all of the aantalstoringen function, its just that line to import the variable which is traced by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

First you give a class name to the div like class="popupDiv". Then you try something like this

```
$('.popupDiv').live('click', function(){
      // var id = $(this).attr('id'); By doing so you will get the current id of the div too.
      centerPopup();
      loadPopup(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Brad correctly said, you don't have to know the amount of such elements, you can just iterate over all element having `id` starting with something.

So your code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^="storing"]').click(function() {
        centerPopup();
        loadPopup();
    });
});
```